# what association test is the best for categorical (ordinal) variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I have two variables:
Variable A (dichotomous): positive/negative
Variable B (ordinal, three level): disease/ maybe disease / no disease.

I want to test the association between these two variable, a chi-square test would treat variable B as nominal.
Which statistical test is more appropriate? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How do you measure your ordinal variable? Is it a physician rating of disease likelihood? (Let’s go with “likelihood” in the colloquial sense, not the technical sense in statistics.)

Comment: @Dave I have noticed three different ways that "likelihood" is used colloquially. The first appears to be Boolean: e.g. "X is likely" or "X is unlikely". The second is comparative: e.g. "X is more likely than Y", "X is less likely than Y", or "X and Y are equally likely". The third is the assignment of an ordinal score: e.g. "On a scale of one to <D> how likely is X". Is a physician's rating of disease likelihood similar to the ordinal case?